# How to verify value contains multiple strings in XCUITest

Tags: swift, swift5, xctest, xcuielement

In an XCUITest (UI test), is it possible to find a label that has three substrings in it?

For example, if I wanted to find a label with "contentsA", "contentsB", and "contentsC" in it, is there a wild card or some other way

I tried this

```
let labelValue = "contentsA with blah blah blah contentsB with blah blah contentsC"

let a = app.staticTexts.containing("contentsA")
let b = app.staticTexts.containing("contentsB")
let c = app.staticTexts.containing("contentsC")

Assert(a && b && c)
```

But this didn't work as expected.

Comment: Is this really swift code?

Comment: It would not do what the OP wants, but it’s what UI test code looks like more or less

Comment: Your code looks like UI test code, not unit test code. You may want to look into MVVM and do assertions on the view model that your view controller consumes. UI Tests are very slow compared to unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an `NSPredicate` to `containing`, which would allow more complex querying

Something like this:

```
app.staticTexts.containing(NSPredicate(format: 
  "label CONTAINS 'contentsA' AND label CONTAINS 'contentsB' AND label CONTAINS 'contentsC'"))
```

Comment: Possible to provide some examples

Comment: https://nspredicate.xyz/#compound-comparison and https://sahil-insights.medium.com/xctest-wait-for-elements-using-expectations-nspredicate-6a6ead0ee8da

Comment: @jacobcan118 I put in an example to try